# infinite two column div grid

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an infinite two column grid. It will automatically arrange div in two columns. For example I have 10 divs, I would like to arrange the into two columns and five rows. For eleven divs, I would like to still have two columns, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/g4v63rnz/
It is an infinte container of two blocks, you can add as many elemnts inside the structure will remain the same.

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>  
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>    
  <div class='innerDiv'></div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #container  {
   width:500px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:pink;
   display:inline-block;
  }

.innerDiv {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:40%;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:4%;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```